# Returning the node and related nodes of the node with the most relationships

Tags: neo4j

In the Northwind Graph worked example provided by neo4j I can find the supplier with the most products with the query:

```
MATCH (s:Supplier)-[r]->(p:Product)
RETURN s, COUNT(r) as c
order by c DESC
limit 1
```

What I'm trying to do is return the supplier with the most products along with their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the `Product` to the `RETURN` statement:

```
MATCH (s:Supplier)-[r]->(p:Product)
RETURN s, COUNT(r) as c, collect(p)
order by c DESC
limit 1
```